# How to prevent labels if height is not large enough to accomodate label using matplotlib bar_label helper function

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
labels = [Jan, Feb, Mar]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p1= ax.bar(labels, data1, width=.75, label='data1')
p2 = ax.bar(labels, data2, width=.75, bottom=data1,label='data2')
p3 = ax.bar(labels, data3, width=.75, bottom=np.add(data1,data2).tolist(),label='data3')

ax.bar_label(p1, label_type='center', color = 'w', weight='bold',  fmt='$%.0f')
ax.bar_label(p2, label_type='center', color = 'w', weight='bold',  fmt='$%.0f')
ax.bar_label(p3, label_type='center', color = 'w', weight='bold',  fmt='$%.0f')
ax.bar_label(p3, padding=3, weight='bold', color = 'gray',  fmt='$%.0f')
```

The code above makes a stacked bar chart and I am using the bar_label helper function to label each bar with the value, but I am having trouble finding how to remove the label if the height of the bar is not tall enough. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an explicit list of strings for the labels. And leave those empty for values that are very small. You can also increase the y margins to leave more space for the labels on top.

Here is some example code, using loops to avoid repetition.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
data1 = np.random.randint(1, 20, 3)
data2 = np.random.randint(1, 20, 3)
data3 = np.random.randint(1, 20, 3)
labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bottom = 0
patches = []
for data, barlabel in zip([data1, data2, data3], ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']):
    patches.append(ax.bar(labels, data, bottom=bottom, width=.75, label=barlabel))
    bottom += data
for data, p in zip([data1, data2, data3], patches):
    ax.bar_label(p, labels=['' if d < 3 else f'${d:.0f}' for d in data],
                 label_type='center', color='w', weight='bold')
ax.bar_label(patches[-1], padding=3, weight='bold', color='gray', fmt='$%.0f')
ax.margins(y=0.10) # more space above bars
plt.show()
```

[image: bar_label skipping low values]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is very helpful.  I am curious about a situation where this is a graph that is being updated every month where the numbers could vary greatly and the if d < 3 might not work i.e. the numbers on the y-axis are much larger. Perhaps this is not a solvable problem. I am wondering if there is a way to make some kind of a scale comparison rather than number comparison.

Comment: Yes, of course, the preferred cut-off value will depend on your specific situation. For example, instead of `if d < 3` you might use `if d < 0.05 * (data1+data2+data3).max()`.  Or `if d < 0.05*ax.get_ylim()[1]`. Or ...

Comment: Wonderful! I was thinking the later and got that to work out nicely. Thanks again!